# php how to find all child nodes of a given node

Tags: php, xml

My XML input is like this:

```
<Configuaration>
    <Allowances>
        <payhead>
            <code>123</code>
            <name_en>Basic</name_en>
            <source>anything</source>
        </payhead>
    </Allowances>
    <Deductions>
        <payhead>
            <code>444</code>
            <name_en>House Rent</name_en>
            <source>anything</source>
        </payhead>
    </Deductions>
</Configuaration>
```

What I want is like, in my php function I will give 2 parameters. 1st one is the input xml and 2nd one is the searchTag (all child nodes under this tag should return).

my php function:

```
<?php
class myXMLUtil
{
    public static function getValue($inputXML, $searchTag)
    {
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        $dom->loadXML($inputXML);
        $childs = $dom->getElementsByTagName($searchTag);
        foreach ($childs as $child) {
            echo '<'.$child->nodeName.'>'.$child->nodeValue.'</'.$child->nodeName.'>'.PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

so if i put the_xml_string and 'payhead' as the function parameter then it should return

```
<payhead>  
    <code>123</code>  
    <name_en>Basic</name_en>  
    <source>anything</source>  
</payhead>  
<payhead>  
    <code>123</code>  
    <name_en>Basic</name_en>  
    <source>anything</source>  
</payhead>
```

but instead i get

```
<payhead>123Basicanything</payhead>  
<payhead>444House Rentanything</payhead>
```

I dont understand it. Can anybody help? If there is something wrong in my code then how can I achieve it? TIA.

Comment: ["nodeValue: The value of this node, depending on its type. Contrary to the W3C specification, the node value of DOMElement nodes is equal to DOMNode::textContent instead of NULL."](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need this function:

```
class myXMLUtil
{
    public static function getValue($inputXML, $searchTag)
    {
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        $dom->loadXML($inputXML);
        $foundElements = $dom->getElementsByTagName($searchTag);
        foreach ($foundElements as $foundElement) {
            echo $foundElement->ownerDocument->saveXML($foundElement);
        }
    }
}
```

You can run locally this code:

```
<?php
$xml = <<<EOF
<Configuaration>
<Allowances>
    <payhead>
        <code>123</code>
        <name_en>Basic</name_en>
        <source>anything</source>
    </payhead>
</Allowances>
<Deductions>
    <payhead>
        <code>444</code>
        <name_en>House Rent</name_en>
        <source>anything</source>
    </payhead>
</Deductions>
</Configuaration>
EOF;
class myXMLUtil
{
    public static function getValue($inputXML, $searchTag)
    {
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        $dom->loadXML($inputXML);
        $foundElements = $dom->getElementsByTagName($searchTag);
                foreach ($foundElements as $foundElement) {
                        echo $foundElement->ownerDocument->saveXML($foundElement);
                }
    }
}
myXMLUtil::getValue($xml, 'payhead');
?>
```

And it will return

```
<payhead>
    <code>123</code>
    <name_en>Basic</name_en>
    <source>anything</source>
</payhead><payhead>
    <code>444</code>
    <name_en>House Rent</name_en>
    <source>anything</source>
</payhead>
```